# jQuery - How to display a simple tooltip when the user's mouse hovers on top of a hyper-link?

Tags: jquery

I have designed a website navigation as follows:

```
Home | Login | Help
```

When the user's mouse hovers on top of the item (i.e. Home or Login or Help), I would like to show a simple tooltip such as (Go to Homepage, or Please Login in, etc.)

How can I do this in jQuery without any plugin?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you want to do it without a plugin?

Unless you insist on re-inventing the wheel I'd suggest [jQuery Tools Tooltip](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html).

There are also several questions on [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+tooltip) already.

Answer (score 4):

No need for jQuery - simply edit your HTML:
You can use the `title` attribute of the `a` element (the link), for example:

```
<a href="loginPage" title="Please Login">Login</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specifity the title='tooltip' in the tag definition in the html

Answer (score 1):

There are many jQuery plugins for tips.  I really like [QTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/) and for a simpler version [VTip](http://www.vertigo-project.com/projects/vtip).

Answer (score 0):

There are several jQuery plugins for this, among them [QTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/), [VTip](http://www.vertigo-project.com/projects/vtip) and [jQuery Tools Tooltip](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html) and I'd really recommend using one of them instead of reinventing something others have already invented.

However, I recommend you use the `title` attribute as a fallback option for browsers without javascript. You can easily take the text from the attribute and feed it to the plugin, and then remove the attribute using jQuery.